# using exists and having count to find rows with highest values by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to select the top 3 rows from a songwriter without using top or max and filtering on name.

the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (Name VARCHAR(10), song VARCHAR(10), length INT )
INSERT INTO Person
values 
('Jim', 'songA', 8),
('Jim', 'songB', 5),
('Jim', 'songC', 7),
('Jim', 'songD', 4),
('Jimsky', 'songE', 8),
('Jim', 'songF', 6);
```

the query:

```
SELECT  
        p1.Name,
        p1.song,
        p1.length
FROM    Person p1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM Person p2
        WHERE p2.length < p1.length
             AND p1.Name = 'Jim' 

        )
```

How can i select the top 3 or top 2 rows without top/max from the songwriter Jim, with having count?

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you:

```
SELECT  
        p1.Name,
        p1.song,
        p1.length
    FROM    Person p1
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM Person p2
        WHERE p2.length < p1.length
             AND p1.Name = 'Jim' 

        )
ORDER BY <SomeRow> DESC LIMIT 3
```

but I don't understand your context, so can you explain a bit more what you are going to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using `row_number()`, assuming you want the three longest songs:

```
select Name, song, length
from (select p.Name, p.song, p.length,
             row_number() over (partition by p.name order by p.length desc) as seqnum
      from person p
     ) p
where seqnum <= 3;
```